# docker python:2-alpine isn't working in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: python, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When I try to build a pipeline it gives me an error "Failed to run image 'python:2-alpine'. Error: docker: Error response from daemon: the working directory 'C:/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile/AppData/Local/Jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/simple-python-pyinstaller-app/'

this is what I have jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent none 
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'python:2-alpine' 
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'python -m py_compile sources/add2vals.py sources/calc.py' 
                stash(name: 'compiled-results', includes: 'sources/*.py*') 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you give the whole error message? If so, try to confirm the JENKINS HOME to user home folder. Currently your JENKINS HOME is in window system32 , it's not a good practice. I'm  not sure your issue is due to folder permission of system32